# UART Receiving in LPC1768

Tags: c, embedded, uart

The `uart_Rx()` receives a character and stores it in a local variable and at the end return that local variable to the function. I have used the timer to control the execution time.

The new problem which I am facing is that my UART is not able to change baud rates as soon as a break is appeared in the loop.

Following is my code to read character.

Please advise if I am doing anything wrong.

```
char read()
{
    flag0=0;
    timer0_init();
    timer_count =0;
    uart_rxChar();

    while(1)
    {
        if(timer_count<300)
        {
            if(uart_RxChar()>=97 && uart_RxChar()<=122)
            {
                uart_TxChar('k');

                if(timer_count>=299)
                {
                    LPC_GPIO2->FIOCLR=1<<13;
                    Glow_GreenLED();
                    delay_ms(100);
                    flag0 = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Glow_RedLED();
                    LPC_GPIO2->FIOCLR = 1<<8;
                    break;
                }
           }
           else if(timer_count>300)
           {
               LPC_GPIO2->FIOCLR = 1<<8;
               Glow_RedLED();
               delay_ms(100);
               LPC_GPIO2->FIOCLR = 1<<13;
               break;
           }
    } 
}

//UART Receiving Function

char uart_RxChar()
{

  while(util_IsBitCleared(LPC_UART0->LSR, SBIT_RBR)); //Wait till data is 
  received
       char data = LPC_UART0->RBR;
  return data;

}
```

Comment: What you are doing a bit wrong is formatting your code. Please try to indent correctly, and try not to forget braces

Comment: Changing baud rate and receiving / transmitting characters are orthogonal functions. When you are about to change baud rate you have to stop communication until it's done. See any bluetooth driver how it works.

Comment: Why do you want to change baud rate dynamically?

Comment: The test 'if(timer_count>300)' is likely always false, because it is in a block executed only when (timer_count<300). Or, at least it is bogus and insecure.

Comment: There is a project we are working on which requires baud rate to be changed dynamically @barny

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error @linuxfan